# Compare data of two tables, store common data in a third, else in fourth table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have four tables having same structure. Say they have a column name in them. I need to check if values in column name of `table1` is present in column `name` of `table2`.

If present, I need to insert this name in column `name` of `table3`, else in column `name` of `table4`.

Comment: INSERT or UPDATE? MySQL or Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `INSERT` and Postgres ...
I would use a [data-modifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) (Postgrs 9.1+) with one `SELECT` and two `INSERT`:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT t1.name, t2.name IS NULL AS t2_missing
   FROM   table1 t1
   LEFT   JOIN table2 USING (name)
   )
, ins AS (
   INSERT INTO table3 (name)
   SELECT name FROM cte WHERE NOT t2_missing
   )
INSERT INTO table4 (name)
SELECT name FROM cte WHERE t2_missing;
```

The same is not possible in MySQL (no CTEs, not to mention writable CTEs).